# How to convert a visualforce page to PDF and preserve the visualforce styles at the same time?

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I want to convert a Visualforce to Pdf and preserve the visualforce css styling the same time in the generated PDF. I am able to achieve the first part using the attribute `renderas='pdf'`. However the styles are getting lost. Any pointers if and how both can be achieved at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

When we add `renderas='pdf'` then Salesforce create PDF in server side in that process we lost many CSS which are not compatible with Salesforce's PDF engine.

You can try `renderAs="advanced_pdf"` to render in PDF. It support much better CSS but also have some limitation. You can read them in details here: [Use Advanced PDF to Render Visualforce Pages as PDF Files (Pilot)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_advanced_pdf.htm).

Another thing which you can do is `renderas='{!DynamicType}'` you can also pass a dynamic type(HTML or PDF) here and based on your use case display the rendered PDF or a normal Visualforce page.

Comment: advanced_pdf is still in pilot last time I checked?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal yes thats why I have mentioned that it has some limits as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a downloadable, printable PDF file of a Visualforce page using the PDF rendering service.
Convert a page to PDF by changing the  tag.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
```